# How to mock class implementing multiple interfaces and cast the mock object back to the class type?

Tags: c#, .net, class, interface, moq

The Calculator class implements multiple interfaces.

```
public class Calculator : IAdd, ISubtract, IMultiply, IDivide
{
    ...
}
```

How would I mock this class, using Moq, and pass is to MyMethod?

```
public int MyMethod(Calculator calculator)
{
    ...
}
```

I mocked IMultiply, for instance, and tried to cast it to Calculator but it became null.

Comment: Since `MyMethod` takes a `Calculator`, you'll have to create a `Mock<Calculator>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To directly answer the initial question, the `Calculator` class can be mocked as is

```
Mock<Calculator> mock = new Mock<Calculator>();
```

Moq allows for specific derived types to be extracted for setup using `As<T>()`

```
Mock<IMultiply> multiplyMock = mock.As<IMultiply>();
multiplyMock.Setup(...);

var subject = new MyClass();

subject.MyMethod(mock.Object);
```

---

Design wise I would suggest `Calculator` start with it's own interface.

Create a single interface to aggregate the functionality

```
public interface ICalculator: IAdd, ISubtract, IMultiply, IDivide {

}
```

and have `Calculator` derive from that

```
public class Calculator : ICalculator {
    //...
}
```

The method depend on the abstraction

```
public int MyMethod(ICalculator calculator) {
    //...
}
```

And when testing, the interface can be easily mocked as needed.

```
//Arrange
var calculator = Mock.Of<ICalculator>(); //and configure expected behavior

var subject = new MyClass();

//Act
var result = subject.MyMethod(calculator);
```